# Proof for remainder operator on subtraction

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given a>b, a>0,b>0,p>0,
and % being the remainder operator

For finding (a-b)%p, I ran some random cases in python terminal and came up with following, however I am facing difficulty proving it.

```
def mod(a,b,p):
    if(a%p - b%p < 0):
        return (a%p + b%p)%p
    return (a%p - b%p)%p
```

Does this guarantee to be correct for the given conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite right. To see why, take e.g. $a=10$, $b=9$, $p=5$.

Then $a\% p = 0$, and $b\% p = 4$, and so we are in the first case $a\%p - b\% p < 0$.

However, $(a\% p + b\% p)\% p = 4\% 5 = 4$, while $(a\%p - b\%p)\%p = ((-9)\%5)\%5 = 1\%5 = 1$.